# How do I heal my Mo'Creatures ghost Wyvern?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I made a sea wyvern farm with mo'creatures, but one of them suffocated in a wall. It became a ghost wyvern, but it's damaged because of the suffocation. A potion of healing damages it (like it damages all other undead) and I don't want to kill him as a ghost. How do I heal him without using potions of healing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undead creatures can be healed by using Potions of Harming on them.

Comment: Additional note: Poison, wither and regeneration worked differently on undead mobs in the past, mods might do so, too. It's better to test that in Creative first.